# How to reverse a string in ksh

Tags: unix, awk, sed, solaris, ksh

please help me with this problem, i have an array witch includes 1000 lines with number which are treated as strings and i want for all of them to reverse them one by one, my problem is how to reverse them because i have to use ksh or else with bash or something it would be so easy..... what i have now is this, but 
`rev="$rev${copy:$y:1}"` doesnt work in ksh.

```
i=0
while [[ $i -lt 999 ]]
do  
    rev=""
    var=${xnumbers[$i]}
    copy=${var}
    len=${#copy}
    y=$(expr $len - 1)
    while [[ $y -ge 0 ]]
    do  
        rev="$rev${copy:$y:1}"
        echo "y = " $y
        y=$(expr $y - 1)
    done

    echo "i = " $i
    echo "rev = " $rev
    #xnumbers[$i]=$(expr $xnumbers[$i] "|" $rev)
    echo "xum = " ${xnumbers[$i]}
    echo "##############################################"
    i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input file and set the desired output?

Comment: there is no file, its the xnumbers array that hold 1000 integeres but they are treated as string here. so for example 
if i =50 xnumbers[ i ]=784
i expect rev to give me back rev= 487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why we cannot use built in rev function.

```
$ echo 798|rev
897
```

You can also try:

```
$ echo 798 | awk '{ for(i=length;i!=0;i--)x=x substr($0,i,1);}END{print x}'
897
```

Comment: rev can be run in bash i checked, in ksh it doesnt exist :(

Comment: $ ksh
$ echo 798
798
$ echo 798|rev
897
It works for me

Comment: when i try to run rev, i get error `rev:  not found`

Comment: @hedgehog What says `type rev` when you are running `bash`?

Comment: if i use rev in bash it works perfectly, point is i cannot use bash for this :(

Answer (score 1):

If, you can print the contents of the array to a file, you can then process the file with this awk oneliner.

```
awk '{s1=split($0,A,""); line=""; for (i=s1;i>0;i--) line=line A[i];print line}' file
```

Check this!!

```
other_var=`echo ${xnumbers[$i]} | awk '{s1=split($0,A,""); line=""; for (i=s1;i>0;i--) line=line A[i];print line}'`
```

I have tested this on Ubuntu with ksh, same results:

```
number="789"
other_var=`echo $number | awk '{s1=split($0,A,""); line=""; for (i=s1;i>0;i--) line=line A[i];print line}'`
echo $other_var
987
```

Comment: i am not allowed to save them in a file, eveything has to be done through a script and nothing to be saved. isnt there a way to "feed" to this awk script the string i want?

Comment: @hedgehog maybe you can do something like;                  other_var=\`echo var | awk '{s1=split($0,A,""); line=""; for (i=s1;i>0;i--) line=line A[i];print line}'\`

Comment: i think something is not going right with what you showed me now, can you check and report back?

Comment: You can echo a variable and pass it through a pipe to awk, assigning the output to another variable.

Comment: i tried it but its not working correctly, doesnt give an error, but the result it prints out it is the same as the one i enter.... it doesnt reverse it.

Comment: @hedgehog Check my answer

Comment: i also tried :Yes,Master? number="789"
Yes,Master? other_var=`echo $number | awk '{s1=split($0,A,""); line=""; for (i=s1;i>0;i--) line=line A[i];print line}'`
Yes,Master? echo $other_var
789`

Comment: i should suppose that we are running different versions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut`, `paste` and `rev` together, just change `printf` to `cat` file.txt:

`paste -d' ' <(printf "%s data\n" {1..100} | cut -d' ' -f1) <(printf "%s data\n" {1..100} | cut -d' ' -f2 |rev)`

Or `rev` alone if, it's not a numbered file as clarified by the OP.

Comment: if you would use rev you dont need anything else... plus already said that rev is not working on my sstem.

Comment: what do you mean, that i said it was numbered, i only said that i want to pass a string with digits inside and reverse it... thats all