# rand() in for loop in nawk returns always same value -ksh

Tags: unix, for-loop, random, awk, ksh

i am troubling myself too much time now with this rand().

I want to add `1000` random numbers in an array, this is what i have so far, it works ith no error, but rand assigns all the time the same number in the arrays passing. the vary of the random numbers i want it to be from 1 to 999... any ideas whats going wrong?

btw i am running in ksh...

```
nawk  ' BEGIN{ 
    for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
        srand()
        NUMBERS[i]= int(rand()*(999))
        print NUMBERS[i]
    }
}'
```

P.S.
Not a dublicate, no other same question for ksh.

**UPDATED**

```
nawk  ' BEGIN{ 
    srand(1)
    for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
        NUMBERS[i]= int(rand()*(999))
        XNUMBERS[i]= int(rand()*(999))
        print NUMBERS[i]
        print XNUMBERS[i]
    }
}'
```

**UPDATE_2**

So the working code i have is this

```
NUMBERS=`nawk ' BEGIN{ 
    srand()
    for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", 100 + int(rand() * (899)));
    }   
}'`
NUMBERS
#echo $NUMBERS
XNUMBERS=`nawk ' BEGIN{ 
    srand()
    for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
        XNUMBERS[i]= 100 + int(rand() * (899));
    }
    for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
        ver=XNUMBERS[i] "";
                rev = "";
        for (q=length(ver); q!=0; q--) {
                rev = rev substr(ver, q, 1);
               }
        printf("%s\n", XNUMBERS[i] "|" rev );
    }
}'`
```

i am creating two different lists, but the rand() is giving in both the same exact numbers in the same position.... how can i make the second rand give different numbers?????

**Final Update**

Sooooo, to any people reading and have the same problem, the solution is to ue a sleep 1 between the two parts that you call the srand....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `srand()` call *outside* the loop. For the same *seed* value `rand()` would produce the *same* sequence of numbers. `srand()` without any argument uses the current timestamp as seed and the loop probably happens to use the same seed value. Hence, you see the same number.

Comment: screw me.. that was the fault? cant believe it... check please the updated post with the code, i put the srand out of the loop, is it wrong if i add the value 1? i use it for saying, that 1 is the starting value.

Comment: Right, the timestamp resolution is in seconds so your loop will produce the same value on each iteration as long as all the iterations happen within the same 1-second window. If the current time happened to cross from 12:00:01 to 12:00:02 or similar while your loop was running then you'd get 2 values. @hedgehog - Moving srand() outside of the loop is the right thing to do but by using a hard-coded seed value of 1 you're negating the whole point of using srand() which is to get a new seed value for rand() on every call to the script (as long as the calls are 1 second or more apart).

Comment: i see, but i thought i read that the value that you add to srand, so in this case i tried 1, is the starting value of the random numbers, so as i see it its like i am saying pick a random number from 1 to 999... am i wrong?

Comment: It's not "wrong" per se (to use the same fixed seed). But for *same* seed value, rand() will produce exactly the same sequence of numbers. i.e. with `srand(1)`, you'll *always* get the *same* set of numbers all the time (now, tomorrow, next year etc). Typically, that's why *time* is used as seed which is reasonably good seed for most applications.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. It's a **seed** value for rand() so it's somethign rand() uses as a "previous value" when generating it's next random number. It's functionally no different than if you didn't call srand() at all in as much as rand() will produce the same "random" number the first time it's called on each invocation of your awk script. rand() always outputs a value that's `>= 0` and `< 1` so to produce random integers between 1 and 999 is `srand(); print int(1 + rand()*999)`.

Comment: i see your points guys, i sorted it out now, thank you a lot... plus @EdMorton you must really like my posts, i have an answer of yours on every single one :p

Comment: You don't have an answer of mine on this one or your [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36745088/1745001) so I think that might be a slight exaggeration. Not that I don't like your posts, of course :-).

Comment: @EdMorton well, you did comment though :p so that counts hihihihi

Comment: @EdMorton anyways, i got a problem with using this the rand( because i am using it in the same script to make two random lists, and it is giving the same exact numbers in both lists, i need it to give different numbers, SEE UPDATE^^)

Comment: @hedgehog The issue is same as before: srand() most likely gets run with the *same seed* value twice. Just remove the second srand() call from the script.

Comment: i found the sollution..... its because both srand were being run in the same second, so they had same value from time of the pc, i just added a sleep 1 between the two nawk and its working fine :)

Comment: There's no need to introduce a delay, just seed them with $RANDOM or similar instead of the current epoch time, e.g. `awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed) ...`. This: `int(rand()*(999))` will give you numbers from 0 to 998, btw, not from 1 to 999 as you say you want. Please re-read my comments above for how to do what you say you want.